# How to markup expression using sigma notation for sum in MathJax

Tags: support, mathjax

I have had trouble trying to express a sigma sum formula.

Please do not think I have been lazy, I have  been lazy, it is just I have up attempting to work it out after over 2 hours (when my actual question still remains to be written).

I was intending to specify a sigma with a variable ( n) at the top right of it And a (i=1) on the bottom right of the sigma. I have made many attempts, but I cannot have an "=" expression instead of a simple variable (like i on its own).

Many thanks

Comment: Given that the [$\text{Canonical } \mathcal{MathJax} \text{ Tutorial}$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is dozens of pages long, I am glad that someone asked this question *separately*. The [$\mathcal{MathJax} \text{ Tutorial}$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a bit of a slog. I wish people would stop marking questions like this as duplicates. If I ask "How do I write a functor in C++" you should not hand me a 3,852 page comprehensive guide on how to write **C++**

Answer (score 17):

I think you want something like this
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$$

This is given by `\sum_{i=1}^n a_i`.

Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

If you omit the curly braces, then characters will be omitted. For example
Notice the difference when I write `\frac123`
$$\frac123$$
versus `\frac{1}{23}`
$$\frac{1}{23}$$.

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you for offering that.

Answer (score 4):

```
 \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}
```

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}$

---

if you want a bigger sigma so

```
 \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}
```

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}
$

Comment: There are also  `\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}` and  `\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}` giving $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}$

Comment: Please never ever use `\displaystyle` or `\limits` in inline math. It looks horrible.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I think that it looks good, but it is your right to think what ever you want

Comment: [Okay...](http://i.imgur.com/7aumVyh.png)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your are looking for the code for $\sum_{i=1}^n$, which is `$\sum_{i=1}^n$`.

The point here is that the command `_` which makes the lower index just takes the first character of some larger text unless you put curly brackets around the whole text. The same is true for `^`.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was trying to achieve. I made the mistake of having them both I seperate pairs of brackets.